# Overwrite a json after modification in PHP

Tags: php, json

I make a modification in my json with this code:

```
$id = "hotel_name";
$value ="My Hotel";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('datas.json'));
$datas = $json->datas;

foreach ($datas as $category => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $element) {
        if($element->id==$id) {
            $datas->$category->$element->$id = $value;
        }
    }
}

$newJson = json_encode($element);

file_put_contents('datas.json', $newJson);
```

But it do not put all the content in it.

How to solve it please ?

---

My json has the following:

```
{
    "datas": {
        "General": [
            {
                "field": "hotel_name",
                "name": "My Hotel name"
            }
        ]     
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to identify the language you're using (use a "tag").

Comment: You should check the preferences of the file. Now it is read-only.

Comment: @RubenKazumov: I do not understand what your are talking. It puts cotent on it but just a part no all the datas.

Comment: @moutarde: You problem is in the file permissions. What is operation system of you server/computer?

Comment: @RubenKazumov: it's not as the file is perfectly edited. It just not had what I want as my code do not make what I want.

Comment: @moutarde: look! when you editing the file, you working as a administrator or so. when PHP trying to owerwrite the file, it's working as "anybody". OS declines the changes of file.

Comment: @moutarde: read about `chmod` command and run `chmod 666 datas.json` in your file directory.

Comment: @RubenKazumov: you're very amazing guy! I told you 2 times that it's not the problem. The file is already at 666!!

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the $element variable, which contains only your inner most data

```
{
    "field": "hotel_name",
    "name": "My Hotel name"
}
```

If you want more of your data, you will have to reassign your outermost $datas variable and children with the newly updated $element variable. I'd recommend creating an empty variable to store the new data instead of altering the original copy.

Answer (score 0):

You should be encoding datas, not just the last element, right?

```
// before
$newJson = json_encode($element);

// after
$newJson = json_encode($datas);
```

By the way, you might find it easier to work with the data if you convert it to an array rather than object.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('datas.json'), true);
```